# Track changes on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a production server and a development server. The schema is equal on both. I need a tool that, if I do any schema change in the development server, it will create a sync script that I can run on production. The servers are not connected, and I can't get from one server to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a tool that if i do any schema change in the develop server it will create a sync script that i can run on the production.

I would suggest you to take a look at [Redgate's schema compare.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) Its worth the investment.

Note: I have used Redgate's schema and data compare and they are life saver.

Alternatively, you can use [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)

> SSDT includes a Schema Compare utility that you can use to compare two database definitions. The source and target of the comparison can be any combination of connected database, SQL Server database project or snapshot or .dacpac file. The results of the comparison appear as a set of actions that must be taken with the target to make it the same as the source. Once the comparison is complete you can update the target directly (if the target is a project or a database) or generate an update script that has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that instead of relying on a tool to generate migrations for you, that your database schema should be managed like any other part of your code.

Don't just make changes to the development environment and build patches for production later. Make sure development is in the same state as production and write your changes as proper upgrade scripts that transform the database to the desired new form. Each time you need to retest, roll development back to "as production" (by restoring a backup, reverting the VM it lives on if it does, or so forth) and reapply the updates.

That way once it comes to making the change in production you have a set of tested migration scripts ready to run. The same goes for QA and UAT environments if you have those as stages between Dev and Prod.

Also, if you don't already (I'm surprised by how many people don't), keep your database build/migration scripts under source control to maintain change history, aid collaboration, and so forth.